# jpa fetch join query

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

This is how my domain looks:

```
public class Template implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private FieldConfig fieldConfig;
}

public class FieldConfig implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fieldConfigId")
    private Set<Field> fieldSet;
}
```

I want to achieve if I load a template from the db that automatically the fieldConfig is loaded and the fieldSet of that fieldconfig.

my current JPQL:

```
TypedQuery<Template> query = em.createQuery("SELECT t from Template t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.fieldConfig"
                + " fconfig LEFT JOIN FETCH fconfig.fieldSet where t.id = :id", Template.class);
```

my exception:

```
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(80@[()* loopback of 477:9: (node= join )*])
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT t from Template t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.fieldConfig fconfig LEFT JOIN FETCH fconfig.fieldSet where t.id = :id], line 1, column 55: unexpected token [fconfig].
```

Any thoughts on creating such a query?

Comment: Are `@Template` and `@FieldConfig` annotated as entities or configures so in the descriptor?

Comment: yes ofcourse, I didn't include that for readability :)

Comment: The query looks correct to me. What's your JPA engine? Have you tried using AS fconfig to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I'm using EclipseLink, tried adding AS got => Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT t from Template t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.fieldConfig AS fconfig LEFT JOIN FETCH fconfig.fieldSet where t.id = :id], line 1, column 55: unexpected token [AS].

Comment: and if you change LEFT FETCH JOINs to regular LEFT JOINS?

Comment: then it works but then the fieldconfig and the fieldset are not fetched (they are empty)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319913/eclipselink-jpql-glassfish-v3-join-fetch-syntax-problem

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an alias on a join fetch in JPQL, this is disallowed by the spec.

EclipseLink does allow nested join fetch through the query hint,

```
"eclipselink.join-fetch"="t.fieldConfig.fieldSet"
```

Comment: TypedQuery<Template> query = em.createQuery("SELECT t from Template t JOIN FETCH t.fieldConfig"
                + " JOIN FETCH t.theme"
                + " JOIN FETCH t.dataConfig"
                + " JOIN t.fieldConfig.fieldSet fs"
                + " JOIN t.dataConfig.textSet ts where t.id = :id", Template.class); 
        
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH, "t.fieldConfig.fieldSet");
        query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH, "t.dataConfig.textSet");
        return query.getSingleResult();