# Fetch all collections eagerly in JPA

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, jpql

Is it possible to fetch all collections in an entity hierarchy eagerly in a particular query only?

For example,

entity **Department** has a list of entity **Employee**. **Employee** has a list of entity **Address**  and a list of entity **Credentials**. **Department**
 has another list of entity **Project**.

I want to eagerly fetch all these collections (in my real case there are more collections) in a particular query `SELECT dept FROM Department dept` and not in other cases (so can't be annotated with FetchType.EAGER). Is it possible?

I am using Eclipselink.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cant you have collection in Department Entity class like department.getEmployees() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use join fetching, batch fetching, or load groups.

I would recommend batch fetching over join fetching, as it will perform significantly better with multiple collections.

See,

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html

Also,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_batch.htm#batch

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_join_fetch.htm#fetch

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup#Load_Examples

Answer (score 4):

Nested fetch joins are not allowed by JPA, you should use the EclipseLink query hint `eclipselink.join-fetch`. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195252/jpa-fetch-join-query).

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, you need to use [`FETCH JOIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins) statements in your query.

> See also: [Fetch Joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html#ejb3_overview_join_fetch)

Comment: Doesn't it require me to **FETCH JOIN** each collection in the hierarchy?

Comment: @NaveedS Not if you build your query dynamically to include the fetch only when you need it.